# Properties of Parabola / Optimization

Tags: optimization, conic-sections

I've been working through some past papers for an exam which I am due to be sitting tomorrow. In the Conic Sections paper from a couple of years ago, the following question came up:

---

The path of a comet can be modeled by a parabola with equation $y^2=2x$.

The Sun, at S, is at the focus of the parabola, and the Earth, at E, lies along the axis of symmetry of the parabola at a distance of 1 Astronomical Unit from the Sun.

[image: diagram]

What is the closest the comet gets to Earth?

*Notes:* The movement of the Sun and the Earth can be ignored. An Astronomical Unit (AU) is the average distance from the Earth to the Sun.

**Source:** http://www.nzqa.govt.nz/nqfdocs/ncea-resource/exams/2009/90639-exm-09.pdf

---

The parabola adopts the form $y^2=4ax$ so the focus is located at $(a,0)$. $4a=2$ so $a=\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore, S is located at $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ and E is located at $(\frac{3}{2},0)$.

Answers are available for this question, telling me that the shortest distance is $\sqrt{2}$ AU, however I am unable to formulate how this has been derived. Would you mind lending a hand?

Thank you.

Comment: So, you know how to get the distance from $(3/2,0)$ to a point on the parabola, no? The square of the distance is a quadratic itself, and I presume you know how to get its minimum...

Comment: The marking schedule gives $d^2=(1.5-x)^2+y^2$ as the equation for the distance from $(\frac{3}{2},0)$ to the parabola. This is the step that I cannot visualize. Please note that I am a 5th former who has been thrown into a 7th form class last minute. I'm sure that I am just missing something pathetically simple. Thanks.

Comment: ...and you know that $y^2=2x$, right? Now your expression for $d^2$ is a nice quadratic in $x$ whose minimum you can easily find...

Comment: Yes. But I don't know how the equation for the distance from $(\frac{3}{2},0)$ came about.

Comment: It's an application of the Pythagorean theorem. Take a right triangle whose hypotenuse is the segment joining $(3/2,0)$ and the parabola point, and whose legs are parallel to the coordinate axes.

Comment: I'm going to feel dumb when this clicks... Why are the short sides defined as $1.5-x$ and $y$?

Comment: Maybe [this diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yTeDh.png) might help you see how to use the Pythagorean theorem...

Comment: That helps very much! However, I still feel a little lost. Is there a property of a parabola that I am unaware of, as to why I am unable to make sense of why this particular point $(x,y)$ has been selected as being the closest to $(\frac{3}{2},0)$?

Comment: I just took a random point on the parabola. Your task is to find that point $(x,y)$ that gives the minimal distance. My first and second comment is what you use...

Comment: But if you selected any other point on the parabola, you would not be able to form a right-angled triangle. No?

Comment: [What makes you think so?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rrZPs.png)

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I was viewing $(x,0)$ as the focus. Thank you very much for your help! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any point on the parabola is of the form $(b^2/2,b)$.  The square of the distance from Earth of this point is $s^2=(b^2-3/2)^2+b^2$.  To minimize this, take the derivative with respect to $b$, set it to zero, and you will get the value of $b$.  One root will be $b=0$, you can ignore that one as it is a local maximum.